# How to Delete Mac from PC

Tags: windows, bootloader

I just got to know that it is illegal to run Mac OS X on my PC. I already have Windows 8.1 installed, and I just formatted the Mac OS X HDD Drive. When I boot my computer on it takes me to the Mac OS X Boot Loader and it says boot failed and says no Operating System found, but when I put my USB on, it takes me to Niresh Menu, where I can select my Drive to boot Windows 8.1. I am in need of serious help.

Comment: Try booting on a Windows 8 install DVD and do a boot repair, it should reinstall (or at least, try to) a bootloader.

Comment: urm, okay, i'll risk deleting mac of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repair the Windows Bootloader from the Advanced Startup Options.

Here is [a tutorial on how to enter the Advanced Startup](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/open-advanced-startup-options-windows-8.htm). The easiest way should be to boot from a Windows 8 installation media (DVD or bootable USB drive).

Then, select Troubleshooting and look for something like 'Startup repair'. The process should be able to repair the Bootloader, so your computer can boot on Windows 8.

Hope this helps !